# closing a browser tab with window.close() only after function finishes runing

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have the following function injected with Tampermonkey (part of a bigger piece of code)

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if ((e.keyCode == 83 || e.keyCode == 32) && e.ctrlKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    [...document.querySelectorAll('button.btn.btn-primary.pull-end')]
      .filter(x => x.innerText.includes('aaa'))[0]
      .click()
    if (window.location.hash.match(/#*/)) {
      window.close()
    }
  }
}, false);
```

the problem is the tab closes before the click() function finishes
I understand probably I will have to use callback but I can not get it working
any help please

Comment: Put the close in the click callback?

Comment: Call it on the next frame: `setTimeout(() => window.close(), 0)`

Comment: `keyCode` ? We're humans, not robots. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/keyboardevent-keys-codes What's the meaning of 42 anyways ;)

Comment: 32 is the space bar

Comment: @yehsuf I was not asking about 32 ;)

Comment: `if (e.keyCode === 42) life() && universe() && everything()`

Comment: I can't see 42 in my code

Comment: It's a joke from Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you please show me how to put it into the click callback?

Comment: @HaoWu will a timeout of 0 be of any meaning?
when I tried it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way by adding a timeout function and it works fine

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if ((e.keyCode == 83 || e.keyCode == 32) && e.ctrlKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    [...document.querySelectorAll('button.btn.btn-primary.pull-end')]
      .filter(x => x.innerText.includes('aaa'))[0]
      .click()
    if (window.location.hash.match(/#*/)) {
      setTimeout(() => window.close(), 1000);
    }
  }  
}, false);
```